# Comparing two arrays containing strings for anagrams in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, anagram

Forgive me if my code is off. I've still got my head in Ruby on Rails which seems to have subtle differences that are coming out as I learn more "just Ruby," although to be fair I'm not sure my code would pass muster in a Ruby on Rails format. I digress.

I am trying to compare two arrays that contain a set of strings. I want to do a couple things. 1) Ensure that the arrays are the same number of words, otherwise the exercise is moot. 2) Compare the first word in an array with *only* the first word in the second array. In other words, I never want to compare word 1 in array "a" with word 4 in array "b". I'm struggling to find a solution that reorders the characters in any given word, compares it to the reordered characters in the corresponding word in the second array, and prints 1 if it's an anagram (once sorted, the idea is that the two words would be equivalent) or 0 if they do not match.

In the example below, what I *want* it to print is:

0
0
1
1

...but that is not happening. Thoughts? I'm afraid this has to do with local variable issues, but I am not be sure.

```
    a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'pants', 'baa']
    b = ['helio', 'godbye', 'spant', 'aba']

    x = a.length
    y = b.length
    z = 0

    x = y? do
        while z < x do
            if a.find(z).chars.sort.join == b.find(z).chars.sort.join
                puts 1
            else
                puts 0
            end

            z += 1
        end
    end
```

Comment: In ruby, if you ever find yourself using a for, while, until loop, chances are you are doing it "wrong". The iterators that are available are incredibly powerful, it just takes some time to learn them all and when to apply then.

Comment: @Jeff Price That's good to know. I usually feel awkward writing loops, but am not far enough along to perhaps be aware of more powerful solutions.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. In future, consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. There's no rush and a quick selection may discourage other, possibly better, answers. Also, it's a bummer for some to see the green checkmark flash on while they are still preparing their answer. Some posters wait hours, even a day, before making a selection. Of course, some never select an answer--even when good ones have been posted--and that's obviously not a good thing.

Comment: Just thought it should be noted that as far as efficiency, there are more efficient ways of checking if 2 words are anagrams than sorting and comparing them O(nlogn). For example, you can iterate through each word, incrementing a value in a hash at the key of that character by 1 for the first word, then do the same for the second word except decrement the value by 1. Then after all of this, iterate through the hash and see if there are any non-zero values and if so, they are not anagrams O(n).

Comment: @raph, good point, and I like the method you suggest. You could skip the last step, however, provided you've checked beforehand that the two strings are the same size, which would seem like a good idea anyway. That's because you can quit early if the count for any letter goes negative. If that doesn't happen, the only possibility, after the decrementing step, is that all counts are zero.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Noted! Just didn't want people wasting their time on my silly questions if I've already been given the answer plus even more stellar things to think on. I'll definitely be less swift next time though. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[*Edit*:** I've edited my answer to incorporate an efficiency improvement suggested by @raph in a comment on the question (the method `anagram?` below). That may not be necessary, but I thought it was such a good idea that it should get some exposure. I've also given a detailed explanation, as the OP is new to Ruby, as might be other readers.**]**

You might consider doing it as follows.

***Code***

```
def anagrams(a, b)
  return nil unless a.size == b.size
  a.zip(b).map { |aw,bw| anagram?(aw,bw) ? 1 : 0 }
end

def anagram?(aw, bw)
  return false unless aw.size == bw.size
  counts = aw.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  bw.downcase.each_char do |c|
    return false unless counts[c] > 0
    counts[c] -= 1
  end
  true
end
```

***Example***

```
a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'pants', 'baa']
b = ['helio', 'godbye', 'Spant', 'aba']
anagrams(a, b)
  #=> [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

***Explanation***

**`anagrams` method**

For the example above,

```
a.size #=> 4
b.size #=> 4
```

so we don't return `nil` in the first line of `anagrams`.

Next,

```
c = a.zip(b)
  #=> [["hello", "helio"], ["goodbye", "godbye"],
  #    ["pants", "Spant"], ["baa", "aba"]]
```

Assuming for a moment that `anagram?` works as desired:

```
c.map { |e| anagram?(e.first, e.last) ? 1 : 0 }
  #=> [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

[Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) passes each element of `c` (a two-element array) into the block.<sup>1</sup>. It is clearer, however, to decompose  (or "disambiguate") those arrays and assign each of the two words they comprise to a block variable<sup>2</sup>:

```
c.map { |aw,bw| anagram?(aw,bw) ? 1 : 0 }
  #=> [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

The first element passed in is `["hello", "helio"]`, so

```
aw => "hello"
bw #=> "helio"
```

and we execute

```
anagram?("hello", "helio") ? 1 : 0
  #=> 0
```

which is shorthand for

```
if anagram?("hello", "helio")
  1
else
  0
end
  #=> 0
```

**`anagram?` method**

So now let's move on to `anagram?`, with

```
aw = "hello"
bw = "helio"
```

Since

```
aw.size == bw.size #=> true
```

we don't return.

**Count frequency of letters in the first word**

Let me now write the next few lines of `anagram?` slightly differently:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
aw_down = aw.downcase 
  #=> "hello"
aw_down.each_char { |c| counts[c] += 1 }
  #=> "hello"
counts
  #=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}
```

(The last line is there just to show the value of the hash.)

In the first line we create a hash `counts` with a default value of zero. All this means is that if `counts` does not contain the key `k`, `counts[k]` will return the default value. **Very important:** *doing so does not change the hash*!<sup>3</sup>

[String#each_char](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-each_char)<sup>4</sup> passes each character of `"hello"` into the block and assigns it to the block variable `c`. Initially, `c='h'` and `h={}`. We then execute

```
counts['h'] += 1
```

which is shorthand for

```
counts['h'] = counts['h'] + 1
```

Since `counts` does not yet have a key `'h'`, `counts['h']` on the right returns the default value:

```
counts['h'] = 0 + 1 #=> 1
counts #=> {"h"=>1}
```

Similarly, after `'e'` and the first `'l'` are passed to the block, we have:

```
counts #=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>1}
```

However, when we pass the second `'l'`, we execute

```
counts['l'] = counts['l'] + 1
  #=>    1 + 1
  #=> 2
```

and we finish up with

```
counts #=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}
```

**The method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) will become a good friend**

This method is used merely to save some steps. It allows us to write:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
aw_down.each_char { |c| counts[c] += 1 }
```

as

```
counts = aw_down.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
```

and we can also get rid of the line

```
aw_down = aw.downcase
```

by writing

```
counts = aw.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
```

This may seem like a small saving, but there are many other situations where the use of `each_with_object` and other `Enumerable` class methods permit the chaining of methods, which is extremely useful.

**Decrementing letter counts for letters in the second word**

Recall

```
counts #=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}
```

We now execute

```
bw_down = bw.downcase
  #=> "helio"
"helio".each_char do |c|
  return false unless counts[c] > 0
  counts[c] -= 1
end
```

First, `'h'` is passed into the block. As `counts['h'] #=> 1`, we execute `counts['h'] -= 1`, so now

```
counts #=> {"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}`.
```

After passing `'e'` and `'l'` to the block,

```
counts #=> {"h"=>0, "e"=>0, "l"=>1, "o"=>1}
```

but when we pass `'i'`, we find

```
counts['i'] #=> 0
```

(i.e., the default value of zero is returned, and we don't want to set `counts['i']` to `-1`) so we return `false`, having concluded that the two words are not anagrams. (Had the second word been `"heeio"`, we would have returned `false` when the second `'e'` was passed to the block.)

**Do we have an anagram?**

Since two two words have the same length, if we are able to process all characters of the second word without returning `false`, we *must* end up with

```
counts #=> {"h"=>0, "e"=>0, "l"=>0, "o"=>0}
```

(no need to check!), meaning the two words are anagrams, so in this case we would return `true` to `anagrams`.<sup>5</sup> Hence, the last line of `anagram?`.

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> Under the hood, this is what's happening:

```
enum = c.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["hello", "helio"], ["goodbye", "godbye"],
  #                  ["pants", "Spant"], ["baa", "aba"]]:map>
```

Here we can see what elements the enumerator will pass into the block, but sometimes you need to convert the enumerator to an array to get that information:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["hello", "helio"], ["goodbye", "godbye"],
  #    ["pants", "Spant"], ["baa", "aba"]]
```

It is actually the method [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each) that passes the elements of `enum` into the block:

```
enum.each { |aw,bw| anagram?(aw,bw) ? 1 : 0 }
  #=> [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

<sup>2</sup> If we pass `[[1,2],3]` into a block, and the block variables are written `|(a,b),c|`, then `a=>1`, `b=>2`, `c=>3`. This is quite handy. Cool, eh?.

<sup>3</sup>

```
h = Hash.new('pig')
h['dog'] = 7 #=> 7
h            #=> {"dog"=>7}
h[0]         #=> "pig"
h['cat']     #=> "pig"
h[{:a=>1}]   #=> "pig"
h            #=> {"dog"=>7}
```

Note there is a form of [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html) that takes block, which allows keys not in the hash to be added when they are referenced.

<sup>4</sup> Instead of `aw_down.each_char` we could have written `aw_down.chars.each`, but `aw_down.chars` creates an unnecessary intermediate array.  `each_char`, an enumerator, merely passes values as they are required.

<sup>5</sup> We could return `0` rather than `false` and `1` rather than `true`, in which case we could write

```
a.zip(b).map { |aw,bw| anagram?(aw,bw) }
```

in `anagrams`, but wouldn't it be clearer to have `anagrams` return an array whose values are `true` or `false`, rather than `0` or `1`?

Comment: My mind just broke a little. I've just found my homework for the next little bit! Thanks for the answer and for next steps!

Comment: Thanks for the edit...I've researched the various methods that I didn't know (the zip method is a new favorite!) but I've got to be honest: I'm not following the 'anagram?' method. The first line is a duh...tracking there. But the second line...creates a 'counts' variable which is ultimately going to store a hash that (to be safe) downcases each word in the array, goes through each character and does what? The 'with_object' method is getting me, and to be quite frank I don't understand how the Hash.new block works. Would love some pointers to get me to understand better.

Comment: I've add an explanation. I normally do that, for the benefit of those new to Ruby (though they are generally not as lengthy as this one), but sometimes I get wrapped up in the problem and forget about the audience.

Comment: Hot dog! Thanks _so_ much. Expected some links vs. a full out explanation, but this is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have to be rocket science. In fact, so long as you can consistently represent each array, it's a no-brainer:

```
a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'pants', 'baa']
b = ['helio', 'godbye', 'spant', 'aba']
c = ['lohel', 'goedboy', 'spant', 'aab']

def anagram_flatten(array)
  array.collect do |word|
    word.chars.sort.join
  end
end

puts anagram_flatten(a) == anagram_flatten(b)
# => false
puts anagram_flatten(a) == anagram_flatten(c)
# => true
```

I wouldn't worry about partial comparisons when a simple array vs. array comparison is super quick anyway.

Comment: Thanks, and I see what you mean. Although my goal is less to compare the arrays themselves vs. the individual items contained within the arrays, so the partial comparison is actually important to me. The idea perhaps being I would eventually count how many anagrams were contained in the two (or 3, or more) arrays and print that out to the user i.e. "Your arrays contained 2 anagrams." Obviously that logic isn't there, but that's the idea...

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow? I guess the idea would be just two arrays with any number of strings in them. Could be expanded in scope, but would need to initially work with just 2 arrays.

Comment: For `A,B,C,D` and `A,B,X,D` would you expect the result to be 2 or 3? For `A,B,D` and `A,D` would the result be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code, there are only two things that need to be fixed:

- the line `x = y? do` should be `if x == y`
- instead of `array.find(index)` you need to use `array[index]` (concrete examples: `a.find(z)` and `b.find(z)` will become `a[z]` and `b[z]`, respectively)

Here's your code, with these two fixes applied. It [works](http://ideone.com/icQwcC):

```
a = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'pants', 'baa']
b = ['helio', 'godbye', 'spant', 'aba']

x = a.length
y = b.length
z = 0

if x == y
    while z < x do
        if a[z].chars.sort.join == b[z].chars.sort.join
            puts 1
        else
            puts 0
        end

        z += 1
    end
end
```

For a more ruby-idiomatic solution, see [tadman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027624/390819).

Comment: Cheers. Helps if I have the correct syntax, no? And thanks for the introduction to ideone.com/ Will definitely help me around the firewalls at work :)

Comment: Careful with not falling off the end of the `b` array here. `b[z]` will fail if `b` contains fewer elements than `a`.

Comment: @tadman that's currently guarded by the `if x == y` condition

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution!

```
for i in 0..a.length-1
  a[i].chars.sort == b[i].chars.sort ? 1 : 0
end
```

Output

```
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: Similar to the first bit of this from Cary: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27027827/revisions. Much cleaner/simple than my original version. Thanks very much for the hint!

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to help. I wanted to provide an efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def anagram?(arr1, arr2)
  responses = []
  arr1.each_with_index { |val, i| responses.push((val.upcase).split('').sort == (arr2[i].upcase).split('').sort ? 1 : 0 )}
  responses
end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.