# How to create a method that checks if string1 can be rearranged to equal string2?

Tags: ruby

I've taken a stab at writing a method, but when my code isn't running and I'm not sure why.

```
str1 = "cored"
str2 = "coder"

def StringScramble(str1,str2)

  numCombos = str1.length.downto(1).inject(:*)
  arr = []

  until arr.length == numCombos
    shuffled = str1.split('').join
    unless arr.include?(shuffled) 
      arr << shuffled 
    end
  end

  if arr.include?(str1)
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As [*@eugen*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163640/eugen) pointed out in the comment, there's a much more efficient way:

```
str1.chars.sort == str2.chars.sort # => true
```

Original answer:

```
str1.chars.permutation.include?(str2.chars) # => true
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot simpler. There's a method for everything. Thank you!

Comment: Generating all the permutations is overkill. `str1.chars.sort == str2.chars.sort` should be quicker.

Comment: Permutation takes far too much time for longer strings like "isitananagram"

Comment: @eugen True! Updated my answer according to your comment, which is far better.

Comment: There are two things I loved: Simplicity of the solution and the ruby-way to solve it simplity.

Answer (score 2):

**Most efficient method?**

Comparing sorted strings is certainly the easiest way, but you can one do better if efficiency is paramount? Last month @raph posted a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027538/comparing-two-arrays-containing-strings-for-anagrams-in-ruby) that suggested an approach that sounded pretty good to me. I intended to benchmark it against the standard test, but never got around to it. The purpose of my answer is to benchmark the suggested approach against the standard one.

**The challenger**

The idea is create a counting hash `h` for the characters in one of the strings, so that `h['c']` equals the number of times `'c'` appears in the string.  One then goes through the characters of the second string. Suppose `'c'` is one of those characters. Then `false` is returned by the method if `h.key?('c') => false` or `h['c'] == 0` (which can also be written `h['c'].to_i == 0`, as `nil.to_i => 0`); otherwise, the next character of the second string is checked against the hash. Assuming the strings are of equal length, they are anagrams of each other if and only if `false` has not been returned after all the characters of the second string have been checked. Creating the hash for the shorter of the two strings probably offers a further improvement.  Here is my code for the method:

```
def hcompare(s1,s2)
  return false unless s1.size == s2.size
  # set `ss` to the shorter string, `sl` to the other.
  ss, sl = (s1.size < s2.size) ? [s1, s2] : [s2, s1]    
  # create hash `h` with letter counts for the shorter string:
  h = ss.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1}    
  #decrement counts in `h` for characters in `sl`
  sl.each_char { |c| return false if h[c].to_i == 0; h[c] -= 1 }    
  true
end
```

**The incumbent**

```
def scompare(s1,s2)
  s1.chars.sort == s2.chars.sort
end
```

**Helpers**

```
methods = [:scompare, :hcompare]

def compute(m,s1,s2)
  send(m,s1,s2)
end

def shuffle_chars(s)
  s.chars.shuffle.join
end
```

**Test data**

```
reps = 20
ch = [*'b'..'z']
```

**The benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

[50000, 100000, 500000].each do |n|
  t1 = Array.new(reps) { (Array.new(n) {ch.sample(1) }).join}
  test_strings = { true=>t1.zip(t1.map {|s| shuffle_chars(s)})}
  test_strings[false]  = t1.zip(t1.map {|t| shuffle_chars((t[1..-1] << 'a'))})
  puts "\nString length #{n}, #{reps} repetitions"
  [true, false].each do |same|
    puts "\nReturn #{same} "
    Benchmark.bm(10) do |bm|
      methods.each do |m|
        bm.report m.to_s do
          test_strings[same].each { |s1,s2| compute(m,s1,s2) }
        end
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

**Comparisons performed**

I compared the two methods, `scompare` (uses `sort`) and `hcompare` (uses `hash`), performing the benchmark for three string lengths: 50,000, 100,000 and 500,000 characters. For each string length I created the first of two strings by selecting each character randomly from `[*('b'..'z')]`. I then created two strings to be compared with the first. One was merely a shuffling of the characters of the first string, so the methods would return `true` when those two strings are compared.  In the second case I did the same, except I replaced a randomly selected character with `'a'`, so the methods would return `false`. These two cases are labelled `true` and `false` below.

**Results**

```
String length 50000, 20 repetitions

Return true 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare     0.620000   0.010000   0.630000 (  0.625711)
hcompare     0.840000   0.010000   0.850000 (  0.845548)

Return false 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare     0.530000   0.000000   0.530000 (  0.532666)
hcompare     1.370000   0.000000   1.370000 (  1.366293)

String length 100000, 20 repetitions

Return true 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare     1.420000   0.100000   1.520000 (  1.516580)
hcompare     2.280000   0.010000   2.290000 (  2.284189)

Return false 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare     1.020000   0.010000   1.030000 (  1.034887)
hcompare     1.960000   0.000000   1.960000 (  1.962655)

String length 500000, 20 repetitions

Return true 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare    10.310000   0.540000  10.850000 ( 10.850988)
hcompare     9.960000   0.180000  10.140000 ( 10.153366)

Return false 
                 user     system      total        real
scompare     8.120000   0.570000   8.690000 (  8.687847)
hcompare     9.160000   0.030000   9.190000 (  9.189997)
```

**Conclusions**

As you see, the method using the counting hash was superior to using `sort` in only one `true`  case, when `n => 500,000`. Even there, the margin of victory was pretty small, much smaller than the relative differences in most of the other benchmark comparisons, where the standard method cruised to victory. While the hash counting method might have fared better with different tests, it seems that the conventional sorting method is hard to beat.

Was this answer of interest? I'm not sure, but since I had already done most of the work before seeing the results (which I expected would favour the counting hash), I decided to go ahead and put it out.

Comment: Plus one for completeness.